# How to count a javascript array and get output like this?

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have a array like this

```
["5763.34", "5500.00", "5541.67", "5541.67"]
```

i want to count similar values and get a out put like

```
(1 * 5763.34) + (1 * 5500.00) + (2 * 5541.67)
```

any idea how to do this?

Comment: Is your question more about the general method/algorithm, or more about the javascript implementation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Count values:

```
var array = ["5763.34", "5500.00", "5541.67", "5541.67"]
var counts = {};

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
    var val = array[i];
    if (val in counts) {
        counts[val]++;
    } else {
        counts[val] = 1;
    }
}
```

Print them:

```
var strings = [];

for (var k in counts) {
    strings.push('(' + counts[k] + ' * ' + k + ')');
}

alert(strings.join(' + '));
```

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/k46kL/1

Answer (score 0):

do it like this

```
sum = 0
for(i=0; i< array.length; i++){
    sum += array[i] * (i+1)
 }
```

Comment: may be i got your question wrong? do you want to sum them all or what?

Comment: not sum them all just to show the how calculation is done. expected answer is provided above by arnaud576875   Thanks for reply